# Java loop runs infinite

Tags: java, while-loop

I am doing a factorial question with java loop, it asks 1+1/2!+1/3!+...+1/n!, n is positive,
I am using "while" to make it, but the code is run with nothing ：

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    double sum=0,a=1;
    int n=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    while(n>0){

        a=a*n;
        sum=sum+1.0/a;
    }
    System.out.print(sum);

}
```

please help：）

Comment: How about decreasing n?

Comment: `n` will not decreased in the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, your original while loop never ends, because the value of n never changes, meaning that the while condition will always be true (assuming the original value was greater than zero).

Is this possibly what you are trying to achieve?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double sum = 0, a = 1;
    int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    for ( int i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
    {
        a *= i;
        sum = sum + (1.0 / a);
    }
    System.out.print(sum);
}
```

Comment: Hi munyul, yes, I tried this, it is what i want, thanks mate, I am bit lost in loop

Answer (score 6):

```
while(n>0){
    a=a*n;
    sum=sum+1.0/a;
}
```

When do you change `n`? You don't. The condition will be always satisfied and you'll never exit the loop. Consider changing the value of `n` in the body of the loop.

```
 Iteration |   n
-----------+--------
     1     |   n      > 0 ? Yes
     2     |   n      > 0 ? Yes
     3     |   n      > 0 ? Yes
    ...    |
    ...    |
  Forever  |   n      > 0 ? Yes
```

Comment: thanks Maroun, but the n is defined as long as it is a positive number, how can I achieve it if there is no maximum limit for n?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @WangPeiTheDancer how about decreasing the value of n? for example: `n--;`

Comment: but I am using command line arguments input to control n, so for example if n=3, is it not 1+1/1*2+1/1*2*3?

Comment: @WangPeiTheDancer You can set another variable to have the value of `n`, say `i = n` and perform the loop `i` times.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is equal to :

```
while(true){

    a=a*n;
    sum=sum+1.0/a;
}
```

You don't change `n` value ,`n` must be `<=0` to `break` your `loop`.

Comment: it's more like if you wrapped the while(true) in an if(n>0)

Answer (score 0):

Why not try a `for` loop let's say

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double sum=0;
    int  n=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    for(double a=1;a<=n;a++){

        sum=sum+1.0/a;
    }
    System.out.print(sum);

}
```